# Flutter AlertDialog, times dimissal problem

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog, navigator

My app shows a Welcome message through an AlertDialog Widget upon creation of one of its pages. I want to dismiss the dialog automatically after 4 seconds or let the user dismiss it by tapping outside the dialog.

```
  void _showWelcomeDialog(BuildContext context) {

    final displayName = UserPageInherited.of(context).displayName;
    String bodyContent = "Welcome $displayName";

    var dialog = WelcomeAlertWidget(bodyContent);

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return dialog;
        });
  }
```

`welcomeAlertWidget` is a StatelessWidget which returns an AlertDialog.

I call the `_showWelcomeDialog()` function inside a `BlocBuilder` once the bloc enters a particular state, like this:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance
  .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showWelcomeDialog(context));

Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
    setState(() {
    // Here you can write your code for open new view
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
  });
});
```

If the user dismisses the dialog before the 4 seconds are over, and the Future returns, the background Widgets disapears and I'm left with a black screen. I was wondering if anybody could help me avoid this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why use an alert instead of a snackbar?

Answer (score 5):

You can copy paste run full test code below 
You can use a `bool clicked` and `await showDialog` 
If `clicked != null` then do `Navigator.pop` 
For demo, I use 20 seconds

code snippet

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _showWelcomeDialog(context);
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 20), () {
    setState(() {
      // Here you can write your code for open new view
      print("future");
      if (clicked != null) {
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
      }
    });
  });
});

clicked = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return dialog;
  });
```

working demo

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

bool clicked = false;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _showWelcomeDialog(context);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 20), () {
        setState(() {
          // Here you can write your code for open new view
          print("future");
          if (clicked != null) {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

void _showWelcomeDialog(BuildContext context) async{
  //final displayName = UserPageInherited.of(context).displayName;
  //String bodyContent = "Welcome $displayName";

  var dialog = AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
    content: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListBody(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Welcome.'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  clicked = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return dialog;
      });

  print('clicked  ${clicked}');
}
```

Comment: I have apply your way. And it solving my current issue for my intention to dismiss in 5 seconds or dismiss right away if clicked. Alert dialog with future.delayed and also new statefulwidget currently having problem on Navigator Pop. Your solution did help in my current case on first try.